# Is there a way to know what would my rep be if there was no daily cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Out of curiosity, Is there a way to know my rep if there was no daily cap?

Comment: There are queries in the SEDE.

Comment: @juergend I know DE, but I didn't think of it this time! thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are queries in the [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for that like [that one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/328997/rep-without-rep-cap-fixed-with-correct-answer-score).

But keep in mind the data is updated only once a week.

On [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) you would have [41626 rep](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/revision/328993/424986/rep-without-rep-cap-fixed-with-correct-answer-score).

Comment: Did you read the query? it counts all upvotes as 10, how about upvotes on questions? shouldn't that be 5?

Comment: I [fixed it](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/edit/328990), can you confirm if this is correct?

Comment: I see no changes in the query. Did you post the correct link?

Comment: [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/edit/328990)

Comment: Looks good. I added the variable userID: https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/revision/328993/424986/rep-without-rep-cap-fixed-with-correct-answer-score

Comment: looks much better, you should link this one in the answer

Comment: Nopes.. Doesn't work correctly.